# helpers {{#if }} doesn't render with expressjs and express3-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a problem with helpers {{#if}} in my nodejs app using expressjs and express3-handlebars:

app.js :

```
app.get('/view', function (req, res) {
    res.render('view', {
      valeur: true
    });
});
```

html :

```
{{#if valeur}}
   ok
{{else}}
   not ok
{{/if}}
```

'ok' isn't render while valeur is equal to true
('not ok' is always render)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me, based on reading the example usage documentation from [here](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers).

You code is very similar to the following snippet

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        showTitle: true,

        // Override `foo` helper only for this rendering.
        helpers: {
            foo: function () { return 'foo.'; }
        }
    });
});
```

And the template snippet

```
 <!-- Uses built-in `if` helper. -->
  {{#if showTitle}}
    <h1>Home</h1>
  {{/if}}
```

I would recommend debugging your app by showing your variable in the rendered template. For instance:

'view` template:

```
The Valeur is {{valeur}}

{{#if valeur}}
   ok
{{else}}
   not ok
{{/if}}
```

In my personal experience, you will find that the value of the variable (in your case `valeur`) will not be as expected, and may be `null` or even `false`. I am expecting that you may have simplified your app and that there is a side-effect from some other piece of code that is changing that value.

Hope you have figured it out!